# Application running in intelliJ but .jar not running

Tags: java, sockets, networking, jar

I have made two applications(**Server and client**) using sockets in java. It is working fine in **intelliJ**, but when i am making the `.jar` file, client application is not opening while server application is running. But when i close the server application, then the client application opens.

Client:

```
package sample;

import com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


public class Main extends Application {
    static Stage stage;
    static boolean ch = true;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Networking.connect("127.0.0.1", 5000);
        //login scene : opening scene
        //to change the value of stage to primaryStage
        stage = primaryStage;
        if(ch) {

            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"));
            stage.setTitle("Electo");
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.show();
            //stage.getIcons().add(new Image(logo));
        }
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
    try {
            Networking.output.writeUTF("Exit");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, "Server error. Try restarting the app"
                    , ButtonType.OK);
            alert.showAndWait();
        }});
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    //function to connect to database


    public Stage getStage()
    {
        return stage;
    }

    }
```

Server:

```
package sample;

import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Networking {

    public static void connect(int port)
    {
        try
        {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.print("Server is started");

            while(true)
            {
                Socket socket;
                    socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    Thread thread = new ServerThread(socket, input, output);
                    thread.start();
                    System.out.print("Client Accepted");
            }
        }
        catch(IOException exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, "Server error. Try restarting the application"
                    , ButtonType.OK);
            alert.showAndWait();
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the run() method of Server thread class

```
public void run() {
        String line = "";
                while(true) {
            try {
                line = input.readUTF();
                if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit"))
                {
                    this.socket.close();
                    break;
                }
                doWork(line);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, "Server error. Try restarting the app"
                        , ButtonType.OK);
                alert.showAndWait();
            }


            }
        }
```

Client side networking class:

```
package sample;

import com.mysql.cj.conf.DatabaseUrlContainer;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Networking {
    private static Socket socket = null;
    public static DataOutputStream output = null;
    public static DataInputStream input = null;

    public static void connect(String Address, int port) {
        try {
            socket = new Socket(Address, port);
            System.out.print("Connected");
            input = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
            output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, "Server error. Try restarting the app"
                    , ButtonType.OK);
            alert.showAndWait();
            Main.ch = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**ADD:** Here is the exception when i run Client.jar with command prompt.

```
ConnectedException in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
        at sample.Main.start(Main.java:33)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
        ... 1 more
Exception running application sample.Main
```

Comment: both listening the same port?  Seems port occupied. What's the error message?

Comment: @yuanqingfei I am adding the code for networking.

Comment: The problem seems to be in the client-side Network class.  Please add that code.

Comment: @VGR I have added that class

Comment: When you run the client .jar file in a command window or terminal, does it print `Connected`?

Comment: @VGR I have added the exceptions, but it is not coming when i run the code with intelliJ.

Comment: It appears Login.fxml is not in your client jar, so `getResource` returns null.  Examine the contents of the jar file check for Login.fxml.

Comment: Maybe that was because i had Login.fxml file with same name in the server and client folder, when i changed the name of the file to something else it worked. But i cannot understand why that was the case as the folders are different.

Answer (score 0):

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load();
```

Comment: Hi! This answer came up in review as low quality because of its length and content. This happens because code only answers are generally discouraged on SO and should be accompanied by some text explanation of how the code is a solution to the question. Thanks!